# Detecting the device of a crypto mount

Tags: linux, devices, luks, dm-crypt, hot-plug

I have an external eSATA-hdd on an OpenSUSE 12.2 system. The external hdd has an LVM on a dm-crypt partition.

I mount it by powering it up and then doing

```
rescan-scsi-bus.sh
cryptsetup -v luksOpen
vgchange -ay
mount
```

Now when I want to power the hdd down, I do

```
 umount
 vgchange -an extern-1
 cryptsetup -v remove /dev/mapper/extern-1-crypt
 echo 1 >/sys/block/sdf/device/delete
```

Here the device (`sdf`) is currently hardcoded in the script. Can I somehow deduce it in the script from the VG or the crypto device?

Comment: Why do you even need `rescan-scsi-bus.sh` and `device/delete`? Just curious because eSATA (AHCI) hotplug works fine without either one on my system. (And my system is 5+ years old.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can find the information in `/sys/block/$DEVICE/slaves`. If you only have the canonical name you can use `readlink` to get the details, e.g:

```
devdm="$(readlink -f /dev/mapper/extern-1-crypt)"
dm="${devdm#/dev/}"
ls /sys/block/$dm/slaves/
```

If you want to remove all you can just utilize directly the `sys` filesystem:

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/$dm/slaves/*/../device/delete
```

Comment: That gives `sdf1`, not `sdf` - but that's a minor problem.

Comment: @MartinSchröder added a small section how to directly unpower the device as the slaves are already a link to the sys device

Comment: There's a catch22: After the `vgchange -an && crypsetup --remove` the `/sys/block/$dm/` is gone.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of possibilities:

```
:> # 1
:> pvscan
:> # 2
:> vgscan -v extern-1
:> # 3
:> dmsetup table /dev/mapper/extern-1-crypt

:> # 4
:> cd /sys/devices/virtual/block/
:> for dmdev in dm-*; do
:>   if [ xyz = $(< "${dmdev}/dm/name") ]; then
:>     ls -l "${dmsev}/slaves/"
:>   fi
:> done
```

Or take the "dm-" number from `dmsetup ls`.

**edit 1:**

OK, it seems that's been all possibilities except the easy one. After looking at Ulrich's answer I myself have to laugh... Obviously not really looked at `/dev/mapper` for too long despite of happily using it all the time.